# How to open bootstrap popup model from typescript file

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on Angular project, launching popup model when my `function` getting called. I found [example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_lg&stacked=h)  on w3schools but this is has all `html` logic to open it.

I want to open it from `ts` file when `openPopup()` function getting called.

popup model `html` code from given link.

```
<body>
<div class="container">

  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">         
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</body>
```

This is button to open popup

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Open modal
</button>
```

How can I replace this code to `ts` file events ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping - This is purely `Angular` question. If I say ts file it means I want to write in `typescript` file.

Comment: I am only saying this because adding more information will get you more responses . Thats all :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping - oh thats great.

Answer (score 0):

create a variable like this. and remove toggle elements from modal.

```
// in ts
 openModal: false;

//then in button click event:

  <button (click)="openModalClick()"></button>
 //in ts:

  openModalClick(){
  openModal=!openModal;
 }
 //in html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" *ngIf="openModal">

</div>
```

this will work in ts way, if you want to toggle with bootstrap,
then select button with id and use java script .click().